# Error during flutter installation: No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, bin, silicon

I'm on a MacBook Pro with M2 Pro, I'm trying to install Flutter. I already used Flutter with my Previous MacBook Pro Intel based.

Basically, I can install it but there are some path or code problems.

These are the steps I do:

1. I download Flutter stable version for Apple Silicon at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos
2. I put the unzipped file into my $HOME/Developer folder
3. Since I use zshell, in the $HOME/.zshrc file, I do: export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin"
4. I restart the terminal or I do source .zshrc
5. I check if `which flutter` and `echo $PATH`, and it's all ok
6. I try running flutter doctor, or whatever other flutter command (even flutter -v), but I always get the same error:

`/Users/Massi/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter: line 40: cd: : No such file or directory /Users/Massi/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter: line 61: /Users/Massi/internal/shared.sh: No such file or directory`

Two days I'm on this problem and could not figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You said you did `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin` but in the PATH it shows `/Users/Massi/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter`. You have an extra `/flutter` at the end, it's probably the problem. Try to correct the PATH.

Comment: Excuse me, where exactly I have this extra '/flutter' ? I have, on both Macs, the .zshrc open, and the PATH is the same. Then, I think that the /flutter does not refer to a folder but to the executable file, which I checked, and it's named flutter. What's strange is that, if I move into the bin folder, the second error goes away, but the first keeps. While in the other computer, I can run flutter doctor or whatever from ~ directory

Comment: Honestly I don't know why or how it could add that _/flutter_ a the end. Try to restart the computer and setting the PATH again ending flutter path at  _/bin_.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a mac mini M1 and I installed Flutter by following the attached video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McxVTgG_E1Y. Note that is the first time that I have an actual interaction with macOS and that video helped me a lot. You can try a clean installation by following this tutorial

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives the same error